# Can't make text go around an image in html/css

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to solve this problem for hours but just can't

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}

.text1 {
  float: left;
  z-index: 0;
  color: black;
}

#face1 {
  z-index: 0;
  float: right;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">


  <h1 class="text1">Povjerenje</h1>

  <p class="text1" align=l eft>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi eget facilisis justo. Etiam non gravida leo. Integer venenatis massa massa, ultrices ornare ex molestie sit amet. Nulla imperdiet dignissim metus sit amet imperdiet. Etiam fermentum scelerisque
    commodo. Integer porta euismod nisl sit amet tristique. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Maecenas vulputate aliquet orci sed scelerisque. Integer vulputate et dolor at hendrerit. Maecenas aliquam
    elit tellus, sed condimentum felis dictum eget. Sed justo tellus, pulvinar vel egestas ac, scelerisque ut nulla. Nam aliquam ligula quis eros eleifend tempus. Pellentesque rhoncus efficitur elit eget sagittis.ntesque rhoncus efficitur elit eget
  </p>


  <img id="face1" src="http://placekitten.com/100/100">


</div>
```

I have a div container holding an image and text and I wan't to make texrt wrap around the image but it always go below or above the image. What I want to do is automatic wraping of text over the image so I can move it and text will automatically move coresponding to it.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Oh okay, I'll edit it

Answer (score 1):

Put the image inside the paragraph.

```css
.container {
  background-color: white;
}

.text1 {
  color: black;
}

#face1 {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="text1">Povjerenje</h1>
  <p class="text1" align=l eft><img id="face1" src="http://placekitten.com/100/100">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi eget facilisis justo. Etiam non gravida leo. Integer venenatis massa massa, ultrices ornare ex molestie sit amet. Nulla imperdiet dignissim metus sit amet imperdiet. Etiam fermentum scelerisque
    commodo. Integer porta euismod nisl sit amet tristique. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Maecenas vulputate aliquet orci sed scelerisque. Integer vulputate et dolor at hendrerit. Maecenas aliquam
    elit tellus, sed condimentum felis dictum eget. Sed justo tellus, pulvinar vel egestas ac, scelerisque ut nulla. Nam aliquam ligula quis eros eleifend tempus. Pellentesque rhoncus efficitur elit eget sagittis.ntesque rhoncus efficitur elit eget
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use css `float: right;` / `float: left;`

- image must be before the text
- no need to be part of `<div>` with text

```css
img {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

p { 
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" />

<div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi cum doloremque eum impedit, libero modi, natus nulla omnis quaerat sapiente sed suscipit vel? Aliquid corporis cupiditate, dolore dolorem eius facilis hic illo iste libero magni maiores maxime, necessitatibus, odit officiis optio perferendis placeat porro praesentium recusandae repudiandae suscipit tempore totam ullam vel veritatis vitae voluptate voluptatibus? Accusantium aperiam, cum dignissimos dolore est et hic impedit, magnam numquam obcaecati provident quisquam saepe? Amet enim est explicabo impedit in modi nobis perferendis provident totam! Ab, accusantium aliquam aut autem consequatur cupiditate, deleniti dignissimos distinctio dolor ea eveniet excepturi facilis harum id impedit iure iusto laboriosam modi molestiae nam necessitatibus nihil nobis omnis perspiciatis quaerat reiciendis rem repellat rerum sapiente tempore, unde velit vitae voluptates. Ab alias culpa cupiditate dolor dolorem ea esse et eum eveniet ex illo laboriosam natus qui quibusdam quos, recusandae voluptate! Accusamus adipisci alias animi asperiores distinctio dolorem dolorum ducimus ea earum enim eum facilis illo inventore labore maxime molestias nam neque nulla obcaecati, quod quos ratione recusandae soluta sunt ullam ut vero! Esse libero perspiciatis qui saepe sed veniam. A consectetur culpa deleniti doloremque doloribus nobis quaerat quidem quo saepe. Aut error nemo nostrum numquam quae ratione veritatis?</p>
</div>
```